# Prevent notification from being swiped off tray

Tags: android

Is it possible to prevent a notification from being swiped out of the notification tray? Like the usb notifications. If not, is there some sort of listener one can implement for that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making your notifications sticky like this

```
private void makeNotification(Context context) {
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
    NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
    .setContentText("Sample Notification Content")
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_picture)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
    ;
Notification n;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT &gt;= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    n = builder.build();
} else {
    n = builder.getNotification();
}

n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is possible
My notification  class:

```
public class ONots {

    public static Notification notification(Context ctx, String title, int icon,
            long when, PendingIntent pIntent, String contentTitle,
            String contentText,int flags, int defaults){
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(pIntent)
              .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(when).setContentTitle(contentTitle)
              .setContentText(contentText).setDefaults(defaults).build();
        notification.flags = flags;
        return notification;
    }
}
```

somewhere in the code:

```
int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        int flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

Notification notif = ONots.notification(this, shown_top, ico, System.currentTimeMillis(), pIntent, contentTitle, contentText, flags, defaults);

            nm.cancel(_.NAKSNOT);
            nm.notify(_.NAKSNOT, notif);
```

Comment: how do i do this using NotificationCompat.Builder, i cant find a setFlags method or flags field

Comment: @VernonKawonza , no `setFlag` method. use it directly.

Comment: When initializing Notification object i get Required: android.app.Notification, Found: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder

Comment: @VernonKawonza , link and add `android-support-v4.jar`. into your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`.When you set this flag user can't dismiss your notification. For more info refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT)

> Constant Value:   32 (0x00000020)
>
> public static final int  FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Bit to be bitwise-ored into the flags field that should be set if this
>   notification is in reference to something that is ongoing, like a
>   phone call. It should not be set if this notification is in reference
>   to something that happened at a particular point in time, like a
>   missed phone call.
>
> Constant Value:   2 (0x00000002)